# Analytic solutions for $x$ in $0 = c + \sqrt{y_{0} + m_{0} x} + \sqrt{y_{1} + m_{1} x}$

Tags: polynomials, terminology, quadratics, radicals

Is there a name for these types of problems? I have tagged this with `transcendental-equations` but I am not sure this is the case.

Comment: This is an algebraic equation, albeit not a polynomial one, so I removed the `transcendental-equations` tag. Rearranging and squaring twice to eliminate the radicals brings it to a quadratic equation in $x$.

Comment: Sorry if this is too basic of a question but when I square twice, I still see x under radicals since $y_{0} \neq y_{1}$ and $m_{0} \neq m_{1}$. Mathematica result: https://imgur.com/a/AVlKYtv

Comment: I see now. I move one of the radicals to the lefthand side, square, then rearrange to get the remaining radical on the lefthand side.

Comment: Right, that's how you do it. Also, remember that each squaring can potentially introduce extraneous roots, so you must verify each root of the quadratic to check whether it does in fact satisfy the original equation.